I have an issue with the screen not scrolling to the selected category when I choose a category
When I select a category, the screen scrolls down from the very top each time, like in the video I shared below. I want it to scroll from its current position to the selected category, and I still haven't been able to achieve this. Can you help me?
This is the link to the design I made
Can you help me solve the issue of the screen scrolling from the top every time?
I'm trying to do this without using Jetpack Compose.
Here’s what I have done so far :-
MainFragment.kt ;
private fun scrollToCategory(selectedMenu: Menu) {
        val position = menuAdapter.getPositionForCategory(selectedMenu)
        val smoothScroller = object : LinearSmoothScroller(requireContext()) {
            override fun calculateDyToMakeVisible(view: View, snapPreference: Int): Int {
                return super.calculateDyToMakeVisible(view, snapPreference)
            }
            override fun getVerticalSnapPreference(): Int {
                return SNAP_TO_START
            }
            override fun calculateSpeedPerPixel(displayMetrics: DisplayMetrics): Float {
                return 100f / displayMetrics.densityDpi
            }

            override fun calculateTimeForScrolling(dx: Int): Int {
                return super.calculateTimeForScrolling(dx) * 2
            }
        }
        smoothScroller.targetPosition = position
        binding.rcyMenu.layoutManager?.startSmoothScroll(smoothScroller)
    }

MenuAdapter.kt ;
class MenuAdapter(
    private val categories: List<Menu>, private val fragment: Fragment
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MenuAdapter.CategoryViewHolder>() {

    inner class CategoryViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val categoryName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtCategoryName)
        val itemsRecyclerView: RecyclerView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rcyMenuContent)
        val txtDetail: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtSeeAll)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CategoryViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_menu, parent, false)
        return CategoryViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CategoryViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val category = categories[position]
        holder.categoryName.text = category.category_name

        val itemAdapter = MenuContentAdapter(category.items, fragment)
        holder.itemsRecyclerView.apply {
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
            adapter = itemAdapter
        }

        holder.txtDetail.setOnClickListener {
            val categoryId = category.category_id
            val categoryName = category.category_name
            val action = MainFragmentDirections.actionMainFragmentToCategoryDetailFragment(categoryId, categoryName)
            fragment.findNavController().navigate(action)
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = categories.size

    fun getPositionForCategory(selectedMenu: Menu): Int {
        return categories.indexOfFirst { it.category_id == selectedMenu.category_id }
    }
}

CategoryAdapter.kt
class CategoryAdapter(
    private val menuItems: List<Menu>,
    private val onCategorySelected: (Menu?) -> Unit
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoryAdapter.MenuViewHolder>() {

    private var selectedPosition = 0

    private val allDishesItem = Menu(category_id = -1, category_name = "Tüm yemekler", items = emptyList())

    class MenuViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        val itemCategoryName: Button = view.findViewById(R.id.btnCategory)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MenuViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_category, parent, false)
        return MenuViewHolder(view)
    }

    @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MenuViewHolder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") position: Int) {
        val item = if (position == 0) allDishesItem else menuItems[position - 1]
        holder.itemCategoryName.text = item.category_name

        if (position == selectedPosition) {
            holder.itemCategoryName.setBackgroundColor(
                ContextCompat.getColor(holder.itemView.context, R.color.selected_item)
            )
            holder.itemCategoryName.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)
            holder.itemCategoryName.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD)
        } else {
            holder.itemCategoryName.setBackgroundColor(
                ContextCompat.getColor(holder.itemView.context, R.color.background)
            )
            holder.itemCategoryName.setTextColor(
                ContextCompat.getColor(holder.itemView.context, R.color.title)
            )
        }

        holder.itemCategoryName.setOnClickListener {
            selectedPosition = position
            notifyDataSetChanged()
            onCategorySelected(if (position == 0) null else item)
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = menuItems.size + 1
}

